# Best way to implement a matching algorithm without a Backend

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, chat, pubnub

I am working on a project in which people can start chatting to each other and other people can join them eg

User 1 will start a chat and then anyone can join them but I want to make sure only one more person joins ie its 1:1 chat. So what I will do is I will show to every user that User 1 is available to chat but as soon as somebody joins the chat, if others try to chat then they should get error.

For my architecture I am using react native for the mobile app and firebase for backend (As its an mvp right now) For chatting I am thinking of using pubnub which provides channels which other can subscribe to. Now what I want is if two people have already subscribed to the channel I dont want anyone else to subscribe to it. How can I achieve this functionality in my current architecture?

I was thinking if pubnub had something like totalSubscribers() for a channel then I could filter out on my app itself. But what would be the ideal way to deal with this? I know there can be a lot of concurrency issues as well but as the users will still be low initially I thought I can use some approximate solution for now.

I would prefer a solution in which I dont have to create my own backend but use existing SAAS services

Comment: I'll be back with a more in-depth answer but check out PubNub Presence and the hereNow API. See these docs: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/presence/overview

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub Presence

I would suggest that you look at [PubNub Presence](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/presence/overview) which keeps track of the number of subscribers per channel. You can use the [`hereNow` API](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/presence/overview#get-online-users-in-channel) to get the current number of subscribers on a given channel but I would also look into using [Presence Webhooks](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/presence/presence-webhooks) that you can configure to notify your server when subscribers join a channel. Once it hits a count of 2 you can "lock" the channel.

As soon as the channel has 2 occupants, remove it from the "available channels" list that you are making visible in your UI.

That's just a high-level design and it may require a bit more "bolt tightening" but I would recommend contacting PubNub Sales to talk to an Account Manager and Solution Architect to get best practices advice. [PubNub Access Manager](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/security/access-control) will likey be a way to secure access to just two subscribers.